# Where to put ruby file related to test interface in Ruby Sinatra Application

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am currently working on building a Ruby Sinatra app. The main routes are defined in app.rb. And there is also a test folder to store the unit tests. However, I have no idea where I should put the test interface file. The test interface essentially is a set of URLs which invoke special functionality that allows my app to be tested from a browser, and is the foundation of the scalability testing.

It's not appropriate to put the file in app.rb. I considered to put it into the test folder, but it looks weird to put it together with unit tests.

Could you give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is to have different sub folders under test. For example, you may have model folder to test model, integration folder to hold integration test and uni，routes folder to test whether different routes function as anticipate.